# nginx custom 404 error page not working

Tags: node.js, nginx

my nginx file is as follows. I am trying to redirect all 404 requests to to my index.html. There on the client side I have custom client side routing logic that will handle the URL.

But the default nginx 404 page is still getting called. (example: go to http://branches-app.com/Languages/Spanish).

```
http {
   .......
    server {
            listen [::];
            listen 0.0.0.0;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            error_page 404 /index.html;
            location = /index.html {
                    root /var/www/html;
                    allow all;
            }

    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You current configuration looks for the file at: `/var/www/html/index.html/index.html` Try: `root /var/www/html;`

Comment: @RichardSmith, changed it. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! I had an include directive including another conf file that had a server directive that was overriding that in the file i posted above.